# PHP Regular Expression for Bengali Word/Sentence

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, validation

I am developing a web application using **PHP 5.3.x**. Everything is working fine, but unable to solve an issue due to regular expression problem with Bengali Punctuation. Following is my code:

```
$value          = '\u09AC\u09BE\u0982\u09B2\u09BE\u09A6\u09C7\u09B6';
$value          = mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE');
//$value            = 'বাংলাদেশ';
//$value            = 'Bangladesh';

$pattern        = '/^[\p{Bengali}]{0,100}$/';
//$pattern      = '/^[\p{Latin}]{0,45}$/';

echo preg_match($pattern, $value);
```

Whether I pass Bengali word or not, it always returns `false`. In **JavaEE** application I used this Regular Expression

```
\p{InBengali}
```

But in **PHP** it not working! Anyways how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

The PHP preg functions, which are based on PCRE, support Unicode when the /u option is appended to the regular expression.

From [regex in Unicode](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Comment: Yes you are right. Since one and half years this site introduced by me, very helpful and solved regular expression problem of JavaEE. but in sense of PHP made me hopeless.

Answer (score 0):

Just append **u** with the expression as following

```
$value          = 'বাংলাদেশ';
//$pattern      = '/^[\p{Bengali}]{0,100}$'; wrong
$pattern        = '/^[\p{Bengali}]{0,100}$/u'; //right
echo preg_match($pattern, $value);
```

Those are facing problem like me could be enjoy with us.